# Relative paths for include in php

Tags: php, security, directory

I have a common include file to be used in whole website, which is located in home directory.
Now to use relative paths in include I have two options:

Using document root to get to root and then using the path to include my file

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/lib/sample.lib.php";
?>
```

OR

Using chdir to change working directory of the script to home directory, then including my file.

```
<?php 
$what_was = getcwd(); 
chdir("/path/to/roo/directory/"); 
include("/lib/sample.lib.php"); 
chdir($what_was); 
?>
```

I want to ask which of the above methods is good regarding performance and security point of view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think none of them.

Always use some combination of **__FILE__** constant and **dirname()** function.

For example:

```
<?php
  $root_dir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)); // assuming the root dir is 1 directories behind the executed file.
  include($root_dir . "/lib/sample.lib.php");
?>
```

**References:**

- http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.constants.predefined.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.dirname.php

Comment: Later versions of PHP also offer `__DIR__` and `basename()` to make directory traversal difficult (if not impossible).